# What are these pickups?

Tags: doom-2016

I came across these a few times and I wasn't able to pick them up, even though none of my weapons had full ammunition, and even my health wasn't full.

Are they ammunition for a weapon I don't have yet?

[image: Unknown pickup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Hologram Grenade. For proof, check out this longplay at 3:03:40. That explains why you couldn't pick it up, from your screenshot you already have a hologram prepped in your inventory.